# Grabbing the Value of Table element that is set/loaded dynamically

Tags: php, html, dom

I would like to get the value of tag that is set at runtime or dynamically.

I tried using the php DOM, it works with other values in the document that are static, it does not work with the elements that are assigned dynamically. Please help.

index.php:

```
<table >
   <tr>
     <th>heading1</th>
     <th>heading2</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr> 
     <td  id="name"></td>    //value is set at runtime
     <td id="phone" ></td>   //value is set at runtime
   </tr>
</table>
<?php
   $doc = file_get_contents("index.php");
   $html = new DOMDocument();
   $html->loadHTML($doc);

   $searchNode = $html->getElementsByTagName("table");

   foreach( $searchNode as $searchNode ){ 
        $tdtag = $searchNode->getElementsByTagName("td"); 
        $result = $tdtag->item(0)->nodeValue;
   }
    print_r($result);
?>
```

When i change $tdtag = $searchNode->getElementsByTagName("td"); to be $tdtag = $searchNode->getElementsByTagName("th");
it returns:
heading1

Comment: The problem there is that you are trying to access a value that doesn't exist yet. You could probably have another page with the PHP and perform an AJAX call once the DOM finished loading (and the td values were populated)

Comment: @Mindastic thank you so much that makes sense. let give that a try, but I'm confident it will work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should send the page content in the AJAX call and, in your PHP, look for that info based on that content.

Comment: @Mindastic I get you, on that point. The table is populated inside a modal. Is it possible to get the content of the modal instead, after the modal finishes loading?

Comment: Yes, you can send whatever you want to the backend. You can send all the page, if you want. if you are using plain JS you can do document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML ... if you are using jQuery, you can do jQuery("html").html()

Comment: Can you post your code in jsfiddle or another online editor and share it? That way it will be easier for me to help you. Thanks.

Comment: @Mindastic I don't understand what I'm missing here. After your suggestion, I am now at the stage where my AJAX seems to be sending null values to PHP. I used: `var _qname = $('#name').val(); $.ajax({ type :'POST', url  : 'email.php', data : {quote_from: _qname},  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json", success : function(data) { alert($(data).html()););}`. My problem is alert() returns nothing for the data.html parameter. But if I do alert(_qname); just before my AJAX I get the correct value I want. please assist?

Comment: But they are two different things. `success` fires when the servers retrieves a response. I am not sure what you are doing in the server, but you are just sendin, for example `quote_form: "something". Did you inspect your AJAX call and check if you are receiving that on the backend? Then, after receiving it, what do you do with PHP?

Comment: @Mindastic sorry about that, here is fiddle: [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/awyeg35g/1/)

Comment: Where are you setting the values? Why are you using a form if you don't have any input or form's related elements inside? What does your PHP code do?

Comment: In a nutshell, what I'm trying to do is read user input from a modal. when the user clicks submit, i then send email using PHP mail function.

Comment: I have another JS that sets the values: document.getElementById("quote_from").innerHTML = inputfromuser;

Comment: Something like below email.php:                                                                                                     `<?php
    $quotefrom = isset($_POST['quote_from']) ? $_POST['quote_from'] : '';
  ............
    mail($quote_send_to,$quote_email_subject,$quote_email_body,$quoteheaders);

Comment: OK, but with that, you are sending an email and not returning a message to the ajaxcall, so that is why it is showing null on your `success` callback. You should return a `json` message (because you set `json` as your `dataType`). Also, in `success` callback, you don't want to show `.html()`, just log the response in the console. Remember, if you don't return `json`, AJAX will trigger `error` callback instead of `success`.

Comment: Excellent! I just added everything as a reply. Please, mark it as the correct one if that really helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are trying to access a value that isn't set yet.
Page must load first and then you can perform an AJAX call sending the info to the server and set another `.php` as your url. 
So, your JS code should be something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  function sendAJAX() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "your-page.php",
      data: {
        value: jQuery("#name").html()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //data will be your server's response
      },
      error: function(data) {
        //callback called in case of error
      }
    });

  }
});
```

Some notes from code above:
- `<td>` tags doesn't contain values. Their `HTML` content is accessed by `innerHTML` (vanilla JS), `html()` (jQuery)
- You can set your `dataType` in your AJAX call. It can be `JSON` for example. In the case you set `JSON` as `dataType`, you must return `JSON` in your backend. If not, the code will fall in the `error` callback due to a `parseError` exception.

Your `PHP` code:

```
$value = $_GET["value"];
//Do whatever you want with the value;
echo $value; //Or whatever (this will be what AJAX call receives on success
```

Regarding `PHP` code above, i am just doing `echo $value` but it can be another way of printing a result in your page. It will be the page content.